# Laravel: Consulta de tablas relacionadas y eliminación en cascada

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, blade

Soy nuevo en Laravel y tengo muchos errores al tratar de relacionar la información de una tabla (YEGUAS) con otra (EXAMENES) y a su vez garantizar la eliminación en cascadas de registros donde la tabla principal es YEGUAS. La relación es uno a muchos (Una Yegua puede tener muchos Examenes) y no se como declararla. Además en la vista para editar yeguas necesito un select que se llene solo con los clientes asociados a un veterinario:
Las tablas son:

- VETERINARIOS:
- id
- nombre
- email

  .
- CLIENTES:
- id
- vet_id
- nombre
- email
- telefono

.

- YEGUAS:
- id
- vet_id
- client_id
- nombre
- edad

.

- EXAMENES:
- id
- yeguas_id
- diagnostico

.

En web.php tengo:

```
Route::get('/yeguas_list', 'YeguasController@yeguas_list')->name('yeguas_list');
Route::post('/delete_yegua', 'YeguasController@delete_yegua')->name('delete_yegua');
Route::get('/view_examen/{id}', 'ExamenesController@view_examen')->name('viw_examen');
Route::get('/edit_examen/{id}', 'ExamenesController@edit_examen')->name('edit_examen');
Route::post('/edit_examen_action/', 'ExamenesController@edit_examen_action')->name('edit_examen_action');
Route::post('/delete_examen', 'ExamenesController@delete_examen')->name('delete_examen');
```

En la vista yeguas_list.blade.php tengo este enlace:

```
<a href="{{ url('/edit_yegua/') }}/{{$yegua->id}}" class="text-success mr-2">
    <i class="nav-icon i-Pen-2 font-weight-bold"></i>
</a>
```

En el controlador YeguasController.php tengo esta funcíon para editar:

```
public function edit_yegua($id){
    $yegua = Yegua::where('id', $id)->first();
    $clientes = Cliente::all();
    return view('app.yeguas.edit_yegua',compact('yegua', 'clientes'));
}

public function edit_yegua_action(Request $request){
    Yegua::where('id',$request->id)->update(
    array(
        'vet_id' => $request->vet_id,
        'client_id' => $request->client_id,
        'nombre' => $request->nombre,
        'edad' => $request->edad,
    ));
   
   return back()->with('msg', "¡Yegua editada!");
}
```

Pero me esta llevando todos los clientes de la tabla y solo necesito los clientes asociados a un veterinario especifico. Es decir, tengo la YEGUA con id = 5, que corresponde al CLIENTE con client_id = 10 y a su vez este corresponde al VETERINARIO con vet_id = 8. Pues necesito que el select se llene solo con los CLIENTES asociados a ese VETERINARIO especifico con el fin de que si el CLIENTE vende la YEGUA a otro CLIENTE, el VETERINARIO pueda cambiarlo pero solo con la lista de los CLIENTES asociados a el.
Como haria para obtener esta información?... Como comenté no he establecido las relaciones y no se como hacerlo.

Además de esto, debido a la relación uno a muchos entre YEGUAS y EXAMENES, tengo esto en el controlador YeguasController.php:

```
public function delete_yegua(Request $request){
   $yeguas = Yegua::find($request->id);
   $yeguas->delete();
   return back()->with('msg', "¡Yegua eliminada!");
}
```

Con solo esto me eliminaria registros en cascada???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para obtener los clientes del veterinario

```
    public function edit_yegua($id)
    {
      $yegua = Yegua::where('id', $id)->first();
      $clientes = Cliente::where('vet_id', $yegua->vet_id)->get();
      return view('app.yeguas.edit_yegua',compact('yegua', 'clientes'));
    }
```

Este te traerá los clientes relacionados con los veterinarios de la yegua.

Para eliminar en cascada puedes hacer algo sencillo como esto

```
public function delete_yegua(Request $request){

   $examenes = Examenes::where('yeguas_id', $request->yeguas_id)->delete();       

   $yeguas = Yegua::find($request->id);
   $yeguas->delete();
   return back()->with('msg', "¡Yegua eliminada!");
}
```

Primero eliminas los examenes que esten relacionado con la yegua, la unica tabla que elimina registro es examenes ya que es la unica que depende de la tabla yegua..

no tendria sentido eliminar resgistro de clientes y de vetereniarios

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, todo funciona perfecto y he adaptado algunas cosas que entendí a otros módulos de mi proyecto. Por otro lado, en cuanto a eliminar en cascada tienes razón, no tiene sentido eliminar registros en CLIENTES y VETERINARIOS. Pero te cuento algo, el registro de la yegua lo eliminó pero tenia dos examenes relacionados a ella y no los eliminó.

Comment: De nada bro...
Que raro revisa bien el request y mira si esta correcto $request->yeguas_id

de lo contrario intenta sustituir el codigo por el siguiente:

$examenes = \DB::table('examenes')->where('yeguas_id', '=', $request->yeguas_id)->delete();